# (Why) Is it faster to use a jQuery-like selector & execute one of its methods, rather than look up a named function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object, methods

I was wondering if defining some 'shorthand' functions in your own native JS code is faster than using jQuery (or any other library which returns an object). For example, suppose I would want to add a class to an element.

In jQuery I would do:

```
$('#sammpleDiv').addClass('someClass');
```

And in native JS I could do:

```
// for simplicity's sake, the toElem parameter can only be an id
function addClass(toElem, classToAdd) {
  document.getElementById(toElem).className += ' ' + classToAdd;
};
addClass('sampleDiv','someClass');
```

**EDIT: These are the correct jsPerfs [with simple replace](http://jsperf.com/jquery-methods-or-js-functions/5) & [with classList](http://jsperf.com/jquery-methods-or-js-functions/8) that answer this question**

What's faster? According to a [jsPerf I made](http://jsperf.com/jquery-methods-or-js-functions), the native JS implementation was more than 100% slower.

So why is it faster to use `$` and return a new instance of `jQuery.fn.init` object, perform a bunch of find and filter tests and a lot of other operations (what jQuery does in effect), then execute one of its methods rather than look up a named function?

Comment: Your test is severely broken: you *always* add the class name to the end of the `.className` property. The jQuery code won't add the class if it's already there.

Comment: In case you are curious, here's how jQuery implements `.addClass()`: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=addClass

Comment: Because `class="someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass someClass"` is a great idea!

Comment: modified  test: http://jsperf.com/jquery-methods-or-js-functions/5

Comment: Using native class management: http://jsperf.com/jquery-methods-or-js-functions/8

Comment: Thanks for all comments, @NiettheDarkAbsol your touch of humor is appreciated, how silly of me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two mistakes in your jsperf as noted in comments as well:

- jQuery is heavily optimized. `.addClass` will only add it if it isn't already added.
- You don't check for it. You are just appending it using `+=` which creates numerous string instances as it runs for 10,00 times or so, which even crashed my browser `;)`

Dr.Molle's modified [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-methods-or-js-functions/5) shows that by fixing the above things, it is the fastest.

Ah! Niet the Dark Absol has provided even a faster one [here](http://jsperf.com/jquery-methods-or-js-functions/8). It is fast because it uses native `classList` and doesn't manually checks for availability of the class.

Comment: Hey, *my* jsperf is the fastest :p Twice as fast as Dr.Molle's, in fact ;)

Comment: Awesome, sorry for crashing your browser and thanks a lot for the explanations. To all commenters as well, I already suspected something was wrong in my jsPerf :)

Answer (score 1):

When doing test case, you need to be sure that

- Both code does exactly the same;
- There is no error (my browser crashed when running your test).

Now, i've replicated the exact same code that jQuery use to add class and in fact, vanilla JS is faster, by 100%:

**[JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-methods-or-js-functions/10)**

The reason why are simples, less function call and less condition. When using jQuery, you use a function call to select an `id`: `$('#id')` and inside that function, you have some condition to check if it need to create a DOM element or use query selector... You can see the relevant code [here](https://gist.github.com/kagagnon/a13de27760ba1af883c0#file-gistfile1-js-L124).

Then after, the jQuery `.addClass()` also have condition since it is possible to use a function as argument. In those said condition, they use even more function call, slowing the process. Again, you can check the code [here](https://gist.github.com/kagagnon/a13de27760ba1af883c0#file-gistfile1-js-L4082).

Now, JavaScript has evolve and it now have a build-in function to add remove classes. Niet the Dark Absol made a [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-methods-or-js-functions/8) with it. It is the fastest way to add class but why do jQuery doesn't use it? Simply because of the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Thanks for the note on `classList` compatibility (IE10+) !